# Struct node having a array of pointers to struct node in C

Tags: java, c, struct

I am implementing multi bit trie in C. I usually code in JAVA and facing difficulty in declaring and initializing Node struct in C.

In Java, node is something like this:

```
private static class Node {
        private String nextHop = null;
        private Node[] pointer = new Node[(int)Math.pow(2, STRIDE)];     
    }
```

In C, I did in this way:

```
#define STRIDE 3
struct MtNode{
    /* nodes stores pointers to its 2^stride child nodes.*/
    MtNode* nodes;  // 2^stride = 2^3 = 8
    int   nexthop;
};

/* Initialize binary trie node */
MtNode* init_mtnode(){
    MtNode *ret = (MtNode *)malloc(sizeof(MtNode));
    int size = (int)pow(2,STRIDE);
    ret->nodes = (MtNode *)malloc( sizeof(MtNode) * size );
    for (int i=0; i<(int)pow(2,STRIDE); ++i)
        (ret->nodes[i]) = NULL;
    ret->nexthop = -1;
    return ret;
}
```

I am getting errors in init_mtnode() function while initializing a node. Please help and suggest a proper implementation.

Comment: `ret->nodes[i].nodes = NULL;ret->nodes[i].nexthop = -1;`

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And your code should already generate an error for `MtNode* nodes;`. Use a C compiler to compile C code, not a C++ compiler (or change the tag and text)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define STRIDE 3
struct MtNode{
    /* nodes stores pointers to its 2^stride child nodes.*/
    /* you are using C, so struct is needed here */
    struct MtNode* nodes;  // 2^stride = 2^3 = 8
    int   nexthop;
};

/* Initialize binary trie node */
/* in C, struct is needed beefure MtNode */
struct MtNode* init_mtnode(){
    struct MtNode *ret = malloc(sizeof(struct MtNode));
    int size = (int)pow(2,STRIDE);
    ret->nodes = malloc( sizeof(struct MtNode) * size );
    for (int i=0; i<(int)pow(2,STRIDE); ++i)
        /* ret->nodes[i] has type struct MtNode, not struct MtNode* */
        /* (ret->nodes[i]) = NULL; */
        {
            ret->nodes[i].nodes = NULL;
            ret->nodes[i].nexthop = -1;
        }
    ret->nexthop = -1;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop initializing `MtNode ret`,as any how your mentioning size for `ret->nodes`

```
MtNode* init_mtnode(){
    MtNode *ret ;
    int size = (int)pow(2,STRIDE);
    ret->nodes = (MtNode *)malloc( sizeof(MtNode) * size );
    for (int i=0; i<(int)pow(2,STRIDE); ++i)
        ret->nodes[i].nodes = NULL
    ret->nexthop = -1;
    return ret;
}
```